# Is it supported to have Additional fields inside a lookup field contain another lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, site-column

I have 3 lists as follow:-

```
ItemCategory

Item

Invoice
```

the Item list has a lookup field to the ItemCategory list

the Invoice list has a lookup field to the Item list.

now i am trying to get the ItemCategory title inside the Invoice list, but seems this is not available inside the UI, as follow, where the Additional Fields section for the Item list does not contain the lookup field to the ItemCategory list :-

[image]

the only work around i find is to add a lookup field to the Invoice list as well, which reference the ItemCategory,, but in this case i will have duplicate info for the Item and its Category (one inside the Item list and the other inside the Invoice list!!).. any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Not all data types are supported in additional fields. You can check the below document to see the supported/unsupported column types:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

[image]

You may have to an auxiliary column and repeat the Category value via workflow or some js etc.